# Open source JavaScript library for hotel layout planning & reservation details

Tags: open-source, javascript, drawing, reservation

I‘m currently looking for an open source JS library, that allows me to have 2 specific modes:

Edit-Mode:
In this mode, I can “draw” multiple rooms (like shown below) and add some additional information to them, for example the room dimensions, kitchen area, and so on. If I have already saved my “layout”, I can edit it in the future, creating additional rooms, blocks, and so on.

[image]

Presentation-Mode:
In that mode I can see the rooms like shown above. If I click on that room, I can see if it’s already booked - if not, I can open a tooltip, that allows me to see some additional data and CTA buttons if needed.

I thought about using some seating chart libraries to achieve that, but I wasn’t sure if that would do the deal. Any suggestions?